# How to: (method Array) becomes original Array modified by method, and original Array becomes (method Array)

Tags: java, arrays

**Aim**:
Draw automaton by using boolean array gridA of values true or false. (true = print(*), false = print(" ").
this has to be done by printing the same Boolean Array (gridA) several times, but each time giving it the values of a separately calculated Boolean Array gridNext. values of gridNext are calculated based on the original Array(gridA) by method getNewRow.

**Problem**:
using the code given below, only the first two arrays are calculated.
after that it's filled with value false for each index.
I believe the problem is somewhere in either method getNewRow (line 147-154) or in method newCellValueByA line(119-136), but I can't quite find the mistake.

**Question**:
Can someone explain exactly how you
1. print an array (gridA)
2. then give original array (gridA) the values of another array (gridNext)
3. when that other Array (gridNext) is calculated based on the original Array(gridA) by a method (getNewRow)

**reviewing**:
I've been looking over the methods but I'm having trouble finding the mistake. I'm particularly surprised that running the code prints two lines but 100% false for the rest. I figured I should take a look wether gridA is properly given the values of gridNext but I can't find a problem there.

Here's the class declaration and method(execute) that's called in main method

```
  public class Cellulitis{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String gridType;
    boolean [] gridA;
    boolean [] gridB;
    boolean [] gridNext;
    int L; //Always positive. Represents the length of the row of cells (not counting the extra border cells that may be added into implementation)
    int G; //Always positive. Represents the number of generations that should be displayed

    void execute(){ 
      readGeneral();
      /*remove later*/    
      System.out.println("output from execute "+gridA[0]+" output from execute "+gridB[0]);
      readInitialConfiguration();

      for(int n = 0; n < G; n++){ //draw generations
          draw();
          gridA = getNewRow();

          /* This was test material, and will be removed if material above is functional
          for(int m = 1; m < L-1; m++){ //determine each individual cell-value  
              gridA[m] = newCellValueByA(m);
           }//end for-loop
           */

      }//end for-loop

    }//end method
```

This is the method used to draw the automaton. I don't expect the problem to be here.

```
    void draw(){ //draws the current state of the automaton (i.e. the values of cells, on one line of output)
        for( int i = 0; i < L; i++){
            if(gridA[i] == true){
                System.out.print("*");
            }//end if
            else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }//end else
        }//end for
        System.out.println();

    }//end method
```

These methods calculate the method. I expect a problem here (or in execute file)

```
    boolean newCellValueByA(int k){ //returns the value of cell number k for the next time step, according to automaton A
        if(gridA[k] == true){
            if(gridA[k-1] == true && gridA[k+1] == true || gridA[k-1] == false && gridA[k+1] == false){
                return false;
            }//end if
            else{
                return true;
            }//end else
        }//end if
        else{
            if(gridA[k-1] == false && gridA[k+1] == false){
                return false;
            }//end if
            else{
                return true;
            }//end else
        }//end else
    }//end method

    boolean[] getNewRow(){ //calculates and returns a new row of cells for the next time step. This method will probably create a new array
        java.util.Arrays.fill(gridNext,false);
        for(int m = 1; m < L-1; m++){ //determine each individual cell-value  
            gridNext[m] = newCellValueByA(m);
        }//end for-loop

        return gridNext;
    }//end method
```

Comment: That's a lot of code with hard-to-read indentation, a lot of long-winded alternatives to `return someCondition;` and very little explanation of exactly what surprises you. I would strongly advise you to try to reduce this to a *short* but complete example - keep removing bits that don't matter until you've got *just* enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I did wonder if it was too much. I thought I'd add some code to provide context but I'll cut off some of the fat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the code and think I know generally why you have a problem. To directly answer your three questions:

1. The easiest way to print contents of an array: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gridA));`
2. To copy an array, you should probably use the clone() utility. `gridA = getNewRow().clone();` in this case
3. Not sure what you are asking. The array is calculated when the function is called. If you're looking for what is going wrong, my first look at the code makes me confused as how gridA[0] ever gets changed, since you iterate from 1 to L-1 instead of 0 to L-1. That should mean your gridA[0] should never change from being true.

However, why everything is gravitating to false after two iterations is because of this (using a array of length 10 as an example):

First, your array is set to be all true (let T = True, F = False)

`TTTTTTTTTT`

Then, for each index 1 to 9 you check it's surrounding values. If the surrounding values are the same, it gets set to False. Since gridA is what you are comparing to and it doesn't get updated until this nextRow calculation is completed, everything gets set to false except for index 0 (outside bounds of m). This happens for each value 1 to 8:

`TFFFFFFFF?`

For the last loop of the for loop, m = 9, this should give index out of bounds as far as I can tell, because you pass in the highest index (m) to the function newCellValueByA which then references the next index (k+1). Past this, is a bit of a mystery to me since I don't know how you don't error out.

Hopefully the answers to your question 1 can help you figure out what the array is at various points to figure out what is going on a little bit better.

Comment: Funny thing, All it took was gridA = getNewRow().clone();
I have no idea why, but it works much better than gridA = getNewRow();
The matter is now resolved. Thank you for your help!